# Bash Script for Backing up/Gzip files with correct name

Tags: linux, shell-script, filenames, gzip

Having trouble forming a backup shell script for nested vm's
There are multiple filenames (vm1, webserver, sshserver, etc.) with nothing in common other  than .qcow2. I need to store just the filenames and then run the gzip command on each of the files, replacing the two places it mentions the file for the command.

So far I have:

```
for file in /var/lib/libvirt/images/*qcow2
do
gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/$file.qcow2 > /backup/full/$file.qcow2.backup.gz
done
```

This holding the entire filepath to the qcow2 file instead of just the filename itself. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should use only `$file` in the `for` loop (not `$file.qcow2`). You can check that by adding a line `echo $file` in the loop.

Comment: ... and you can use `"${file%.qcow2}"` to remove the trailing `.qcow2` - see for example [Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: @sudodus adding echo $file in the loop spits out `/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm01.qcow2`. my idea would to just get the `vm01.qcow2` portion and then use that shove into the gzip command where needed.

Comment: @steeldriver I actually kind of want the `.qcow2` portion for the gzip command. I am mainly trying to get just the filenam.extension for the filepath.

Comment: Either `cd` to the source directory first, or use `"${file##*/}"` or the `basename` command to remove leading directory components

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! added the `"${file##*/}"` and it works perfectly! much appreciated.